# Can't detect my Android mobile phone in network using NMAP

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ubuntu-12.04, nmap

I want to find all devices using my WiFi connection.

I used:

```
nmap -vv -sP 192.168.1.1-100
```

I can find my local PC and Router, but I cannot detect my Android mobile phone using this command.

network:

```
192.168.1.20   router
192.168.1.34   local pc
192.168.1.33   Android phone
```

nmap:

```
user@Internetcafe-PC12:~$ nmap -vv -sP 192.168.1.1-100

Starting Nmap 5.21 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2017-06-25 12:40 IST
Initiating Ping Scan at 12:40
Scanning 100 hosts [2 ports/host]
Completed Ping Scan at 12:40, 2.71s elapsed (100 total hosts)
Initiating Parallel DNS resolution of 100 hosts. at 12:40
Completed Parallel DNS resolution of 100 hosts. at 12:40, 0.31s elapsed
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.1 [host down]

Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.19 [host down]
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.20
Host is up (0.0029s latency).

Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.32 [host down]
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.33 [host down]
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.34
Host is up (0.00021s latency).
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.35 [host down]
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.36 [host down]


Nmap done: 100 IP addresses (2 hosts up) scanned in 3.02 seconds

user@Internetcafe-PC12:~$ ping 192.168.1.33

PING 192.168.1.33 (192.168.1.33) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.33: icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=121 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.33: icmp_req=2 ttl=64 time=47.1 ms
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this other modificators on Nmap to avoid "ping scan":

```
nmap -sS -sV -vv -n -Pn -T4 192.168.1.1-100

nmap -vv -A -n 192.168.1.1-100
```

You could also add `sudo` before `nmap`, just to ensure you got all privileges.